# Find the last record for a particular ID in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a MYSQL table which looks like this :

```
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
| id  | prev_status | date_modified              |
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
| 236 | INIT        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.128730 |
| 236 | REMS        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.139382 |
| 236 | RET         | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.146587 |
| 236 | PA          | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.150409 |
| 236 | CORR        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.157473 |
| 236 | PA          | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.165941 |
| 236 | SUB         | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.174236 |
| 236 | FILL        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.181169 |
| 236 | SHIP        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.183954 |
| 570 | INIT        | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.320310 |
| 570 | REMS        | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.333153 |
| 570 | RET         | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.340783 |
| 570 | PA          | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.351363 |
| 570 | SUB         | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.360626 |
| 570 | FILL        | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.368099 |
| 570 | SHIP        | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.371222 |
+-----+-------------+----------------------------+
```

As is evident,the data is already ordered by ID.I know **limit 1** will give the last record in the table.However,what i need is the last record for each id.In this particular case, i need:

```
 +-----+-------------+----------------------------+
 | id  | prev_status | date_modified              |
 +-----+-------------+----------------------------+
 | 236 | SHIP        | 2015-11-13 08:00:53.183954 |
 | 570 | SHIP        | 2015-11-13 08:01:13.371222 |
 +-----+-------------+----------------------------+
```

How would i go about doing that ?

Comment: It may not be possible to accomplish this if the extent of your table really be what you have above.  The problem is that MySQL does not really have any internal order for records.  So even though you are seeing the `SHIP` record at the bottom of each `id` group, internally this may not be the case.

Comment: Is there any other column which could be used to order the `prev_status` column?  Would it be acceptable to use alphabetical ordering?

Comment: the prev_status is the various stages an id goes through and it is important that order of the prev_status as inserted  is preserved..sorting it in alphabetical order will screw up the data..

Comment: I strongly recommend creating another `id` column for order of the `prev_status` within a given `id`.  As I mentioned, there is no internal order in MySQL, and what you are seeing may not be reproducible.

Comment: the thing is if i do a groupby by id..it shows me the first record for each id..what i want is the last one..

Comment: There is no "first" or "last" one.  You need to use an aggregate function in the `GROUP BY` to choose a record for each group of `id` values.  Currently, I don't see any way of doing this.

Comment: Whenever you change the status and add a record for it, it should put a timestamp in another field. That way, you can order the records by date.

Comment: yes..that makes sense..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..i now have a date modified column..does that help..

Comment: @amistad yes. Immensely

Answer (score 2):

After the date_modified field is added, The query will be as below

```
select s.id, s.prev_status, s.date_modified from (select * from tab1 order by date_modified desc) as s group by s.id;
```

Comment: Is there a good reason to divert from the documented solutions

Comment: This kind of querying is also documented in Mysql Manual. Please check it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html   Search for "table_subquery"

Comment: But not as a solution to the GROUPWISE MAX problem - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html (and the main page - but NOT the comments! - at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: This query is processing N (Main) + N(Sub) records. It is less than the Cartesian product. Do you have a solution which reduces this number of records getting processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query with self join . In that you don't need to create temp. table.You can use following to get data..

```
**SELECT id,prev_status,MAX(date_modified) FROM  tabelName GROUP BY id;**
```

For more detail you can check [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

Thanks

Comment: Prev_status will be arbitrary- but it almost seems like you knew that

Comment: why will prev_status be arbitrary ?

Comment: yeah..now that i run it,i do notice that prev_status is not the right value..how do i overcome that..

Comment: Here's one way: `SELECT x.* FROM tabelName x JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date_modified) max_date_modified FROM tabelName GROUP BY id) y ON y.id = x.id AND y.max_date_modified = x.date_modified;`

Comment: @Strawberry:  Like I said, there is a difference while processing a Join(Cartesian product) Please check http://pasteboard.co/7TOJYLD.png

Comment: @Thanga. If your solution executes faster than mine on a properly indexed data set, I'll buy you a beer. But the crucial point is that mine returns a guaranteed correct result set. While in practice yours will (in my experience) also always return a correct result, it's not guaranteed - and, as per the documentation, even less so in the latest version of MySQL.

Comment: @Strawberry, In worst case, suppose the records are having duplicates (it happens). Please check how the queries are working http://pasteboard.co/7W7F53P.png . It is because of the missing "distinct" in your query.

Comment: @Thanga Which is why I've explained that the OP's data set includes a redundacy. In a normalized data set, this cannot happen.